# How to pick up a conversation from a frozen chat room?

Tags: discussion, chat

Scenario: Several weeks ago, I had an extended discussion with another SO member in a private chat room (a follow-up to a question I asked and they answered). Now, I am trying out some of the techniques we discussed, and I would like to pick up the conversation from where it left off.

What is the best way to contact the user to resume the discussion? As a user, I would expect to be able to continue the chat (but I can't - the room is frozen), or to send a private message to the other user (which the site doesn't support at all).

I suppose I could comment on his answer, but it would seem out of context, since we've gone quite some length from the original answer and its comments. Other suggestions?

Comment: I suppose it should be perfectly fine to request that the frozen room be unfrozen.  Then you could do an @reply to get the other person's attention.  Do you have a link to the room you wish to unfreeze?  [This one?](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/2389/room-for-highcommander4-and-luc-danton)

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean [this room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/2389) (which by the way is *not* private; there are no private chat rooms except for moderators)? In that case, the other person is pretty active in chat. Just visit their profile, see where they're chatting, join them there, invite them to a new room, whatever.